# Block auto padding-top divi theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, padding

I have problem with "auto" padding-top on my site, 
I want to get rid of the space between menu and video (like on the second print-screen - I have edited padding-top via Chrome browser to 0px). 
Moving up element with CSS margin-top: -80px is not working.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Oeg.jpg

I wrote simple script:

```
document.getElementById("page-container").style.padding = "0px 0px 0px 0px";
```

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl0OB.jpg

It is still "auto" padding-top.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divi sets new inline padding when scrolling.

If you're sure this is the element you want with 0 padding then you can override inline style with css:

```
#page-container {
padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have tried this but without "!important;". 
Worked!

Comment: Cheers! Read more about CSS specificity (and caution for using !important) here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity